# Declaring Foreign Keys (of existing table) in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, mapping

I am back and this time I have a question about SQLAlchemy.

Say I have the following table in some MySQL db:

```
table Table1 (
id1 
id2
primary key(id1, id2)
id1 references Table2.id
id2 references Table3.id
)
```

I'd like to map it using SQLAlchemy, and so I try the following:

```
table_1 = Table('Table1', metadata, Column('id1', INTEGER, ForeignKey('Table2.id'),primary_key=True), Column('id2', INTEGER, ForeignKey('Table3.id'),primary_key=True),autoload=True)

class Table_1(object):
pass

mapper(Table_1, table_1)
```

I tried it, but SQLAlchemy is saying that it cannot find the table with which to establish a relationship. I have tried using an existing database and mapping it with SQLAlchemy and it worked, but it was a simple, test db. It had no foreign keys in it. I think I am lacking some other lines to establish the relationship between the parent table and the child, but looking at the tutorials I've seen aren't helping me that much.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

So this is a snippet of the code that I have made to 'connect and map' to my MySQL DB:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, sessionmaker

from portal.model import DeclarativeBase, metadata, DBSession

bioentry_ec = Table('BioEntry_EC', metadata, Column("bioentry_id", INTEGER, ForeignKey("bioentry.bioentry_id", ondelete='CASCADE')), Column("ec_id", INTEGER, ForeignKey("EC.id", ondelete='CASCADE')), autoload=True)

ec = Table('EC', metadata, Column("id", INTEGER, primary_key=True), autoload=True)

bioentry = Table('bioentry', metadata, Column("bioentry_id", INTEGER, primary_key=True), Column("biodatabase_id", INTEGER, ForeignKey("biodatabase.biodatabase.id", ondelete='CASCADE')), autoload=True)

biodatabase = Table('biodatabase', metadata, Column("biodatabase_id", INTEGER, primary_key=True), autoload=True)


class BioEntryEC(object):
        pass

class EC(object):
    pass

class Biodatabase(object):
    pass

class Bioentry(object):
    pass

mapper(BioEntryEC, bioentry_ec)
mapper(Biodatabase, biodatabase)
mapper(Bioentry, bioentry)
mapper(EC, ec)
```

So these are some of the mappings. I am not sure if I am declaring the Foreign keys incorrectly, or if there is something missing in my code. Take note that the keys in the bioentry_ec table compose a composite key.

When I run turbogears, it tells me that it cannot find biodatabase, even though I have declared it along with the other tables. Am I doing something wrong in my code?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Have you also created mappings for `Table2` and `Table3`?

Comment: Yes, I have made mappings for the other two tables. I thought that SQLAlchemy would be able to 'find' the tables since I have declared them as well. I think that I need to add a line or two that would show the relationship between the tables, but I am not sure what to add. I searched for other info on this, and I stumbled upon using relationship() in SQLAlchemy. But I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: You are right, SA should find all the tables. I do not know how to direct you further though without having more information. Would you be able to show more complete code? Or, are you sure you connect to the right database/schema?

Comment: I can give you a snippet of the code, I suppose. I'll edit my original question to show it.